# how to perform calculation on a dynamic table by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to perform multiplication operation function(calculateAmount) and display it in 'total' textbox..my problem is it works only for first row of the table. what changes have to be done to perform multiplication on all the row of a table.. why its not working for multiple row... and also when i choose the option on the second row it updates the value of the 1st row's textbox.. what mistake i'hve done ?

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createElement("input");
  element1.type = "checkbox";
  element1.id = 'text' + rowCount + '';
  element1.name = "chkbox[]";
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  //var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  //cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var selectList = table.rows[2].querySelector('select');
  var element2 = selectList.cloneNode(true);
  element2.id = 'selected-item'+rowCount;
  element2.name = 'tot_pin_requested'
  cell2.appendChild(element2);

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var element3 = document.createElement("input");
  element3.type = "number";
  element3.className = "form-control";
  element3.title = "Item-name";
  element3.id = 'qty' + rowCount + '';
  element3.name = "it_re_qty[]";
  cell3.appendChild(element3);

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var element4 = document.createElement("input");
  element4.type = "text";
  element4.className = "form-control";
  element4.title = "Item-name";
  element4.id = 'unit-price-' + rowCount + '';
  element4.name = "unit-price[]";
  cell4.appendChild(element4);

  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var element5 = document.createElement("input");
  element5.type = "text";
  element5.className = "form-control";
  element5.title = "Item-name";
  element5.id = 'toatal-' + rowCount + '';
  element5.name = "total-[]";
  cell5.appendChild(element5);

  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  var element6 = document.createElement("input");
  element5.type = "text";
  element5.id = 'tot_amount' + rowCount + '';
  element5.name = "tot_amount[]";
  cell6.appendChild(element6);


}
function calculateAmount(val)
 {
    var tot_price = val * 100;
    var divobj = document.getElementById('tot_amount');
    divobj.value = tot_price;
}

    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
   <table class="table  table-hover" style="background-color:white; text-align: center;" id="item-table">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" id="btn-addrow" onclick="addRow('item-table');" class="btn-success form-control" /></td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th style="text-align: center">Item Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">Quantity</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">unit Price</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td class="col-md-4">
      <select name="tot_pin_requested" id="selected-item" onchange="calculateAmount(this.value)" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" name="it_re_qty[]"  class="form-control"></td>
   
    <td> <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="tot_amount[]" id="tot_amount" type="text" readonly></td>
    
  </tr>

</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: First, your table has` 5 th` and your first row contains only `4 columns` whereas when you add a new row its contains `5 columns`  so it's a little bit confusing plz be specific with columns count.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you are updating element with id `tot_amount`  whichc is the id of 1st row of your table  content, but while adding dynamic rows your element id format is `'tot_amount' + rowCount + ''`  , use `'tot_amount' + rowCount + ''` id while updating the values , You can refer to the below updated code

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createElement("input");
  element1.type = "checkbox";
  element1.id = 'text' + rowCount + '';
  element1.name = "chkbox[]";
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  //var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  //cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var selectList = table.rows[2].querySelector('select');
  var element2 = selectList.cloneNode(true);
  element2.id = 'selected-item'+rowCount;
  element2.name = 'tot_pin_requested'
  cell2.appendChild(element2);

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var element3 = document.createElement("input");
  element3.type = "number";
  element3.className = "form-control";
  element3.title = "Item-name";
  element3.id = 'qty' + rowCount + '';
  element3.name = "it_re_qty[]";
  cell3.appendChild(element3);

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var element4 = document.createElement("input");
  element4.type = "text";
  element4.className = "form-control";
  element4.title = "Item-name";
  element4.id = 'unit-price-' + rowCount + '';
  element4.name = "unit-price[]";
  cell4.appendChild(element4);

  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var element5 = document.createElement("input");
  element5.type = "text";
  element5.className = "form-control";
  element5.title = "Item-name";
  element5.id = 'toatal-' + rowCount + '';
  element5.name = "total-[]";
  cell5.appendChild(element5);

  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  var element6 = document.createElement("input");
  element5.type = "text";
  element5.id = 'tot_amount' + rowCount + '';
  element5.name = "tot_amount[]";
  cell6.appendChild(element6);


}
function calculateAmount(val,index)
 {
    var tot_price = val * 100;
    var divobj = document.getElementById('tot_amount'+index);
    divobj.value = tot_price;
}

    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
   <table class="table  table-hover" style="background-color:white; text-align: center;" id="item-table">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" id="btn-addrow" onclick="addRow('item-table');" class="btn-success form-control" /></td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th style="text-align: center">Item Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">Quantity</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">unit Price</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td class="col-md-4">
      <select name="tot_pin_requested" id="selected-item" onchange="calculateAmount(this.value,this.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex)" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" name="it_re_qty[]"  class="form-control"></td>
   
    <td> <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="tot_amount[]" id="tot_amount2" type="text" readonly></td>
    
  </tr>

</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```